# Creating a grid to draw on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a grid on my website where you can somehow draw on.
There are however a few problems:

1. I want it to be compatible with IE7/8 (hence no HTML5/canvas).
2. I would also like to be able to store the image drawn in the end.
3. The grid has to be able to have several sizes (from 10x10 up to 1000x1000 preferably even more). Probably with a zoom in/out function.
4. I also want to support all RGB colors
5. In addition to this the whole grid should be drawn on a fixed size (i.e. 800x600)
6. NO FLASH
   I however have no idea how to do so, hence I would like to ask if anyone knows a way of doing so.

I have been looking at jquery myself, although I have no idea how I could implement it this way since I never used it before.

edit: added a few more requirements

Comment: go to some freelancing website where you can hire someone or you because here no one is going to code for you

Comment: There's [sketchpad](http://ianli.com/sketchpad/) using [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com).

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble No, I wish to do this myself since it's a project of my own and I wish to learn from it. By giving it away to some other person who I have to pay money is simply a bad idea.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Looks very interesting, I'll take a look at it

Comment: If you really wish to learn then flash may help you

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble Oh, I also forgot to add that but I refuse to use flash.

Comment: For a layout grid, you might try http://960.gs/

Comment: @JaredFarrish I looked at the Raphael library and that seems to be PERFECT to what I want to do! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you are only wanting to save the image drawn and not the grid lines, why not use an image?

Have several images in the sizes you want. that way you arnt putting extra processing on the browser.

you can just use an image in the smalles grid size and tile/repeat it on the background. Should be a fairly small image and a fast load

Comment: You are not completing his third requirement

Comment: which part? the different size grids would be easily done. as for the zooming, like you've said, no one is going to code it for you.

Comment: Not only do images indeed make the third part hard, I do not feel like making over a million different images. Since obviously, I want to support all RGB colors..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly; you want a grid with cells, the user can select a color en drag/move over the cells to draw something. Then when the user is happy, then they must be able to save the picture to continue on it later..

I will describe what I would do if it was my project (jQuery and CSS).

I would start with a list:

```
<ul id="grid"></ul>
```

Then I would create the grid with li for the rows and div's for the cells. You can set the size and color of the cells with CSS and jQuery.

Here is a simple example of the generate grid and the event for the cell.

```
function createGrid() {
    $('#grid').html('');

    for(var row = 0; row < total_rows; row++) {
        $('#grid').append('<li id="row_' + row + '"></li>');
        var current_row = $('#row_' + row);

        for(cell = 0; cell < total_cells; cell++) {
            $(current_row).append('<div id="cell_' + cell + '" class="cell"></div>');

            //set events
            $('#cell_' + cell).mouseenter(paint_cell);
        }
    }
}

function paint_cell(event) {
    //mouse down?
    if(event.which==1) {
        //give it a color
        $(this).addClass('red');
    }
}
```

Simple CSS:

```
.cell {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
}

.cell .red {
    background: red; //all the rgb you want ;)
}
```

You'll need a javascript function that loops trough all the rows and cells and saves the information in a xml file or something to be able to save the drawing. And you'll need one to read the xml and generate the grid based on the information.

For bullit 5; you can wrap the grid in a div and set the width and height to 800x600 and the CSS to overflow: scroll.

Hope this helps you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw whatever you want with colored spans
Here is a [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxemt/2/) that can be a start to develop further.